# Testing for significance of two coefficients in same t-test

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, t-test

I need to perform a t-test at the 0.05 significance level to test whether two coefficients are significant. My degrees of freedom are 96. When looking for my t-critical do I need to affect my level of significance since I am testing for the significance of two coefficients in the same test ?